# String handling in Ada

Tags: string, ada

I'm trying to define an array of Strings in Ada to store Strings of variable size.
The problem I have is that I must pre-define the size of my Strings which I don't know at compile time, and with
the Unbounded_Strings the String_Split.Create wouldn't work, as it requires Standard.String.

Below is my code, where I need to be able to parse Strings of variable size, and not
just the fixed length 4.

Thanks in advance.

```
type StrArray is array(1..7) of String(1..4);

function Split(Line : String;Sep : String) return StrArray is
    Tokens : String_Split.Slice_Set;
    Output : StrArray;
    Count : Natural := 0;
begin
    String_Split.Create(s => Tokens,
                        From => Line,
                        Separators => Sep,
                        Mode => String_Split.Single);

    For I in 1 .. String_Split.Slice_Count (Tokens) loop
         Count := Count + 1;
         Output(Count) := String_Split.Slice(Tokens,I);  -- Not sure how to convert                Slice_Count to Integer either!
    end loop;

    return Output;

end Split;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that `GNAT.String_Split` uses `String` doesn’t mean that your `StrArray` has to. And you need to cater for input strings with varying numbers of tokens, so begin by declaring `StrArray` as an unconstrained array type:

```
type StrArray is array (Positive range <>)
  of Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;
```

Now `Split` begins like this:

```
function Split (Line : String; Sep : String) return StrArray is
   Tokens : GNAT.String_Split.Slice_Set;
begin
```

(we can’t declare `Output` yet, and we won’t need `Count`; and I had to go to Google to find out that `String_Split` is a GNAT utility package).

The first thing to do is to split the input line, so that we know how large `Output` needs to be (by the way, do you really want `Single`?):

```
   GNAT.String_Split.Create (S => Tokens,
                             From => Line,
                             Separators => Sep,
                             Mode => GNAT.String_Split.Single);
```

Now we can declare `Output` using the `Slice_Count`. Note the conversion to `Natural` (not `Positive`; if the input is an empty string, there will be no tokens, so the output will be an empty array, range `1 .. 0`).

```
   declare
      Output : StrArray
        (1 .. Natural (GNAT.String_Split.Slice_Count (Tokens)));
   begin
```

Now fill `Output` with the tokens. AdaCore chose to implement `Slice_Number` as `new Natural`, rather than as a subtype of `Natural`, which is why we need the conversion.

```
      for I in Output'Range loop
         Output (I) :=
           Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_Unbounded_String
             (GNAT.String_Split.Slice
                (Tokens, GNAT.String_Split.Slice_Number (I)));
      end loop;
```

... and return `Output`, within the declare block.

```
      return Output;
   end;

end Split;
```

To call `Split`, which is going to return a `StrArray` whose length you don’t know beforehand, you can use the technique of [constraint by initial value](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-6.html#p30):

```
declare
   T : constant StrArray := Split ("goodbye  world ", " ");
begin
   for J in T'Range loop
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("'"
                              & Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_String (T (J))
                              & "'");
   end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks heaps, it works. Just wondering now, how to know the length of Output in the function which calls the Split(), in order to declare a StrArray to hold the output. (it seems that in ADA I can't do : Split("line",",")'Range ) Cheers.