# How to get a smaller string from an unbounded string

Tags: string, ada, words

I am having trouble reading in a line from a file and then breaking it up into its individual words. Let's say that I read in "When the night was young" because that was the first line, I cannot figure out how to just get the word "When" away from the rest of it, I've tried multiple times, and I've run out of ideas. I'm fairly new to unbounded strings in Ada and just Ada in general. Any help is appreciated, little hints or the solution to my problem, thanks.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;                   use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;         use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Text_IO; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Text_IO;

with AVL; use AVL;

procedure Spellchecker is
   InWord      : Unbounded_String;
   ReadIn      : String (1..20);
   Break       : Character := ' ';
   RevisedWord : String(1..20);
   Dictionary  : File_Type;
   Paragraph   : File_Type;
   Count       : Integer;
   LastChar    : Integer;
   NewTree     : Tree;

   type Spell is array (Integer range 1..20) of Character;
   Revision : Spell;

begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Open (File => Dictionary,
                     Mode => In_File,
                     Name => "dictionary.txt");
   loop
      exit when End_of_File (File => Dictionary);
      InWord := Get_Line (File => Dictionary);
      Insert (InWord, NewTree);
   end loop;
   Close (File => Dictionary);
   Print (NewTree);
   InWord := Get_Line (File => Paragraph);
   Count := 1;
   Put (InWord);
end Spellchecker;
```

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22857680/40851) helpful. I know it uses a GNAT-specific library, but it does the splitting.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two options:

- You can convert the `Unbounded_String` to a regular fixed-length `String` and operate on that.
- You can look up the subprograms `Index` and `Slice` in the section of the reference manual describing `Ada.Strings.Unbounded`, and use those to find spaces and cut the `Unbounded_String` appropriately.